# aws codecommit - gnutls_handshake() failed: Decrypt error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I am trying out amazon codecommit for one of my project. After all the steps mentioned by amazon on this document - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/codecommit-user.pdf

When I am trying to clone the repository. And I am getting the following error. 
Though I have answers related gnutl_handshake() error, none found have Decrypt error. Does anyone know why this happening? How can I resolve this.

```
git clone https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/mycode code
Cloning into 'code'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/mycode/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Decrypt error
```

Comment: Related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-failed-when-connecting-to-https-servers?

Comment: Thank you @jarmod. That worked.

Comment: Great! I'll add it as an answer so you can accept it and future people will be able to find the answer quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here seems to be with the gnutls package, particularly if connecting to an HTTPS server while working behind a proxy. See [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-failed-when-connecting-to-https-servers) for options to replace gnutls with openssl.